# Plink command results not being saved to local text file

Tags: cmd, putty, plink

I am calling a remote ssh through PuTTY's Plink functionality - I am able to connect and run my commands but not able to store Output into another text file - my script is as:

```
plink ssh_hostname -m "directory\till\inputCommand.txt" -l username -pw password > "directory\where\OutputTxt_Will_Be_Saved\OutputRes.txt"
```

Here `OutputRes.txt` is created, but it is completely blank. The result is shown on the command line, but not saved into `OutputRes.txt` (that's what I want to save on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command probably prints its output to an error output stream, not standard output stream.

To capture the error stream, add `2>` redirection:

```
plink ... 2> "directory\where\OutputTxt_Will_Be_Saved\ErrorRes.txt"
```

To capture both standard and error outputs to the same file, use `2>&1`:

```
plink ... > "directory\where\OutputTxt_Will_Be_Saved\OutputRes.txt" 2>&1
```

See [Using command redirection operators](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).